# show text content without refresh using Jquery/php

Tags: php, jquery

I wanted to show textbox content without refreshing,so I used Jquery
I have problem with this part: `name:form.name.value` what does this exactly do?And why I have problem?when entering it will show nothing

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function get(){
$.post('msql.php',{name:form.name.value},
function(output){
$('#mydiv').html(output).show();
}
);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="name">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="button" name="but" value="Check" onclick="get();">
<div name="mydiv"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

msql.php:

```
<?php
 echo $_POST['name'];
 ?>
```

Comment: When you use Firebug or chrome developer tools, you get no javascript error message in the console?

Comment: No I don't have any error in firefox,what do you mean with developer tools?

Comment: i mean when using google chrome, you can open a javascript console via   wrench button->tools->javascript console. that way, if your javascript has error you can see it and you can also do anything you do on firefox via firebug

Comment: it was interesting I went to web developer web console in firefox but I can't work with it how It can understand where my jquery.js is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="but"]').click(function() {
        alert("start");
        $name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
        $.post('msql.php', {
            name: $name
        }, function(output) {
            alert(output);
            $('#mydiv').html(output).show();
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

html:

```
<form id="form_name">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="button" name="but" value="Check">
</form>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: why not using that and what it will do?

Comment: @nikparsa change `name="mydiv"` by `id="mydiv"`

Comment: @nikparsa `$(document).ready` to wait until doc is loaded, `input[name="but"]` means get input that have name but,`$('#mydiv')` get element that have id tag mydiv, `return false` to avoid form submition

Comment: why having three functions?what do you mean avoiding form submition?

Comment: @nikparsa the first for doc ready the second for click event the last for php doc complete load

Comment: ` $('input[name="name"]').val();`  what does this mean? the first name is which one name and the second one is which one?

Comment: @nikparsa get value of the input that have tag name equal to "name"

Comment: Thank you mgraph for the helps:)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the period (`.`) just after `html`.

it should be `$('#mydiv').html(output);`

Also, you'll be better off using mgraph's solution but remove the period I just told you about.

I don't think jquery understand what `form.name.value` is unless you provide it with a proper selector like mgraph suggested.

Comment: Thanks about the dot yes But nothing changed